# YCM vim plugin not picking up C++ header files

Tags: c++, vim, plugins, header

In our C++ project some of the header files (the ones that use qt) have extension 'hq'. I'm trying to get YCM plugin of vim to work for those files. I found similar threads from a few years ago but no luck.

Is there an easy way to tell YCM that it should treat those files as normal C++ headers ?

Comment: Use the plugin's official support channels.